# Creating a join where I pull a count from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have a table with real estate agent's info and want to pull `firstname`, `fullname`, and `email` from rets_agents.

I want to then get a count of all of their sales from a different table called `rets_property_res_mstr`.

I created a query that doesn't work yet so I need some help.

```
SELECT r.firstname, r.fullname, r.email
from rets_agents r
LEFT JOIN rets_property_res_mstr
     ON r.email = rets_property_res_mstr.ListAgentEmail
LIMIT 10;
```

I'm not sure how to get the count in this.

Comment: Do a GROUP BY, and use COUNT().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for aggregation:

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.fullname, a.email, COUNT(p.ListAgentEmail) cnt
FROM rets_agents a
LEFT JOIN rets_property_res_mstr p ON r.email = p.ListAgentEmail
GROUP BY a.firstname, a.fullname, a.email
ORDER BY ?
LIMIT 10;
```

Note that, for a `LIMIT` clause to *really* make sense, you need a `ORDER BY` clause so you get a deterministic results (otherwise, it is undefined which records will be shown) - I added that to your query with a question mark that you should replace with the relevant column(s).

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a CTE for this:

```
WITH sales as (
SELECT ListAgentEmail, count(*) count_of_sales
FROM rets_property_res_mstr
GROUP BY ListAgentEmail
)

SELECT r.firstname, r.fullname, r.email, count_of_sales
from rets_agents r
LEFT JOIN sales
     ON r.email = sales.ListAgentEmail
LIMIT 10;
```